# Python ThreadPoolExecutor max_worker default value

Tags: python, multithreading

**In Python's official document, quote -**

> Changed in version 3.5: If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5, assuming that ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for ProcessPoolExecutor.

(https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/concurrent.futures.html)

This reads very contradictory to me, as it also states that Python's threading cannot utilize multiple cores in the machine.

> In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

**Question:**
Why does max_workers default to "number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5"? And what exactly does the reasoning here "assuming that ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for ProcessPoolExecutor." mean?

**Edit:Since Python3.8**

> Default value of max_workers is changed to min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4). This default value preserves at least 5 workers for I/O bound tasks. It utilizes at most 32 CPU cores for CPU bound tasks which release the GIL. And it avoids using very large resources implicitly on many-core machines.

Still, it looks like `max_workers` is optimized when it's more than # of CPUs. Does this imply that ThreadPoolExecutor can utilize multiple CPU cores ?

Comment: There are multiple situations where the GIL is released. One if them is when it is waiting for I/O. Which is exactly the assumed case for the statement.

Comment: And to answer your specific question.  Yes, ThreadPoolExecutor can use multiple CPU cores.  The principal difference between multithreading and multiprocessing is that the threads all run in a single address space, while processes are independent of each other.

Comment: You should check out the difference between IO bound and CPU bound tasks. Multithreaded Python has no issues utilizing multiple cores for IO bound tasks. However in the case of compute intense CPU bound tasks the GIL won't be released so multithreading is not your option there, rather use multiprocessing. Each approach has its ups and downs so it to master them will require you to do more research.

Comment: As [GIL document](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) says, some extensions (which are not implemented in python) can intentionally release GIL. So, if there is a CPU-bound module that releases GIL, it is possible to utilize multiple cores with ThreadPoolExcecuter. Although, I think the reason why the default value is so high is simply because "better too big than too small". Which is mostly true for IO-bound tasks.

Comment: Thank you guys. Your explanations are right, but still it doesn't sound like the ThreadPoolExecutor can utilize multiple CPU cores *at the same time*. In that case, I do agree for I/O bound tasks, it's better to have multiple threads to switch back and forth and during that the GIL will be released and re-acquired. However I don't understand why it's recommended to be higher than number of cores if it's not utilizing multiple cores at the same time.